# PHP-Javascript Problems in Firefox, IE Explorer, but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer, firefox

My problem is a little bit hard to explain.

I'm working in `Goddady.com`, with `php`, `mysql` and `javascript` code. 
It is a little web software, with a login, a poll and all the data is saving in a `mysql` database. 
The php code is deprecated because of the Goddady php version.

The program is working fine in my localhost.

Here is some of the code that gives me some warnigns:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = $usr;
$_SESSION['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = $pwd;
$_SESSION['autentificado'] = "0";

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$dbname = '';

mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) OR DIE ('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');

mysql_select_db($dbname);

    $query = "SELECT password FROM comercial where usr = '".$usr."'";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result) {

        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

I can do the login in the web page without problem, but, when I change to another php page, that has another conection to the database, in `Firefox` and `IExplorer` it returns a:

> the connection has been reset (a Browser error, not PHP error)

The connection in the oder php page is like:

```
$hostname = 'localhost';  //$hostname='.db...com';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$dbname = '';

mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) OR DIE ('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');

mysql_select_db($dbname);
$query="SELECT * FROM encuestaacromega "
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

First I have a `<body onload="poll.php">` (onload redirection). When I have that in Chrome it gives me an:

> err_empty_response

and a blank page as well.
I have change that, and now in Chrome is working fine.

I don't know, in some error that I have seen in stackoverflow some people says that Goddady ban possible web software that could work as a "robot".

As I say, all the problems are ocurring in `Goddaddy.com`. In my `localhost` is working fine.

More inputs... 
In Chrome I've to change a `<form>` with a `submit` to a `" for resolve the issue in that explorer.

Any help would be apreciate.

Thanks!!

Comment: `mysql_*` is depreciated, you might want to consider moving away from this as you fix your issue.